# Playing with strings in C++, analysing characters and creating functionality through a class

Tags: c++, string, class

I've been playing around with this C++ book I picked up a while back and have gotten into the section with strings,(and I'm playing with classes). So far I've had to work with for loops and some basic function stuff. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to analyze a string for certain things.
The book asks me to try to scan a string to see how long it is, and to count how many vowels there are in the string. Plus it wants me to count the string according to it's ASCII numbers and add it up. That last one is a bit odd, but if it says it's possible, then who am I to argue?

I had seen some post online that said someone was trying to scan for upper and lowercase letters, so I figured I might as well try that out as well. I'm also trying to see how classes work as well, and this seems like a good way to play with that process.

I think I have the class structures down, at least as far as a default constructor goes, and functions, (stll a bit iffy on the overloaded constructors and what part they play)

The book shows some examples, but admittedly, sometimes it doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

As far as the code goes, I've been trying this

```
string usrWord;   

string vowel = "aeiou";

string::size_type vowel2;
vowel2 = usrWord.find(vowel,0);

string::size_type wordL;
wordL = usrWord.length();

cout << "This has " << wordL << " characters in the string, and " << vowel2 << " vowels. << endl;
```

I have no idea how to do the ASCII thing, and am wondering if this is good enough for checking character sizes? (like how I'm looking for vowels).

Comment: Read more about [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), it doesn't search for a set of characters in a string, but searches for a substring.

Comment: What does it mean to search for a substring?

Comment: A substring is a smaller string taken from a larger string. For example, lets say you have the string `"Hello world!"`, then you have multiple _substrings_ like `"Hello"` or `"world"`, and any combination of consecutive letters in the original string (including (but not limited to) `"H"`, `"He"`, `"Hell"`, `"l"`, `"ll"`, `"lo wo"`, etc.) To search for such a substring you can use `std::string::find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string str ("Find the vowel");
unsigned found = str.find_first_of("aeiou");
while (found!=std::string::npos)
{
   cout<<"\n found "<< str[found];
   found=str.find_first_of("aeiou",found+1);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you create an instance of a string called str, and pass Find the vowel into it, which I get. What is the unsigned for? can that not be a sting or a char? I've read about find_first_of, but doesn't that only look for one, or the first, of whatever your trying to find? Is that what the +1 is for in the while loop, so long as npos hasn't been reached, (i'm assuming the end of the string), then keep looking, even if you find 1 vowel?

Comment: Here's a question. I was playing around with this to see how it works, and I set it up to take in user input for the string, but it only analyses the first word in a sentence. How do you get around that? I thought strings were supposed to be able to go past the first word

Comment: @MichellePeoples If you use the stream input operator `>>` to read into a `std::string`, then the input operator stops at whitespace (i.e. space, tab, newline). So the input operator for strings only read words. To read a whole line you e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: That worked perfectly! I used in in my user input spot in my main. Is that a way to use it in the function so that it will always look at a whole line, or is that just overdoing it?

Comment: How would you do a count on the vowels that has an actual number as opposed to just printing out the vowel it finds as it goes along?

Comment: Oh, and one more question, why do you have found set as unsigned? shouldn't it just be a char or and int? Not too sure what unsigned is, gonna have to go look it up....